# Centering the contentView within UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller

In my UIViewController that I use for my UIPopoverController, I have a label on top, a segmented control, and then a UITableView below it.  When I created my .xib for the content view, I put in a table, and centered the label and segmented control within the .xib.

When I present the popover, I do not want it taking the whole screen.  I use about (800,700) points to display the popover, but then the labels do not look right.  They are not centered within the popover since the popover is now smaller than the .xib.  What I did was move the label and segmented control to the left to make it centered in IB.  That doesn't seem the best and future proof way of doing it.  I was hoping I could do something programatically by taking the width size and dividing by 2 or something and centering based on that.  Any advice?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options:

1. Check out the documentation for the popoverContentSize property on the UIPopoverController, you should set it to be the size of the XIB that provides the content (so the XIB and popover both have the same size/contentSize, essentially).
2. Set the autoresizing masks on the subviews in the XIB so that they lay themselves out correctly dependant on the size of the XIB. To center them within their parent view you do NOT want the left and right mask setting (they should both be deselected in Interface Builder). This guide covers centering subviews: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling